# Discount on categories but how to exclude already discounted products

Tags: discount, catalog-price-rules, price-rules

I need to discount some categories in a magento shop which is not a problem. But I would like to exclude already discounted items in shop that has been setup manually on the products.

So I need a rule which includes the categories and exclude the items which already are on sale.

I hope someone can help me out.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you set up the Catalog Price Rule, you can choose **Discard subsequent rules** under **Action**.

Comment: How can i exclude 5 specific categories? Actually discount applied for all products, i need discount not apply to selected 5 categories

Comment: @Rathinam You can set "Category is not <categiry_id>" under "Conditions"

Comment: Shall I ask regard add to cart button

Comment: You can do the same on Cart Price Rule

Comment: How to display Name, Thumbnail Image, Price, Add-to-cart Button On CMS PAGE, workout: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQvpO.png,  https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk0ui.png  Code -> https://justpaste.it/6avne   Add to cart button not working, can  you pls help me.

Comment: Please ask a new question for this :)

Comment: someone post this -> pls reply your solution -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/237560/57334

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82052/discussion-between-rathinam-and-py-yick).

Answer (score 0):

Hi create a Shopping Cart Price Rule same as below given images[image]